# How to convert timestamp from a dataframe column to a just day number?

Tags: python, pandas

1 - I try convert the column "Days" to just days number of days -> "-1 days +08:22:13.269259" to "-1"

2 - and column deadline to just a date -> "0021-06-09 00:00:00" to "09-06-21"

```
>>>new['Days'] = (datetime.datetime.today() - pd.to_datetime(new['Deadline'], format=("00%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
>>>df
    Days                         Deadline
0  -1 days +08:22:13.269259     0021-06-09 00:00:00
1   0 days 08:22:13.269259      0021-06-08 00:00:00
2  -1 days +08:22:13.269259     0021-06-09 00:00:00
3  -1 days +08:22:13.269259     0021-06-09 00:00:00
4  -2 days +08:22:13.269259     0021-06-10 00:00:00
5  -1 days +08:22:13.269259     0021-06-09 00:00:00
6  -2 days +08:22:13.269259     0021-06-10 00:00:00
7  -2 days +08:22:13.269259     0021-06-10 00:00:00
8  -6 days +08:22:13.269259     0021-06-14 00:00:00
9  -6 days +08:22:13.269259     0021-06-14 00:00:00
```

1 - I get erro "timedelta64[ns]' does not match format '%d'"  when I try convert to days number

```
new['Days'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(new['Deadline']), '%d')
```

2 - I get erro "Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 21-06-11 00:00:00" when I try convert timestemp to data in this format ("%d-%m-%y")

```
new['DME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DME'], format=("00%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")).date

OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 21-06-11 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

Firstly create a mask via `startswith()`:

```
df['Deadline']=df['Deadline'].astype(str)
cond=df['Deadline'].str.startswith('00')
```

Then pass that boolean mask and use `to_datetime()` method:

```
df['Deadline']=pd.to_datetime(df.loc[cond,'Deadline'].str.lstrip('00').append(df.loc[~cond,'Deadline']),yearfirst=True,errors='coerce')

df['Deadline']=df['Deadline'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%y')

df['Days']=df['Days'].dt.days
```

Output of `df`:

```
    Days    Deadline
0   -1      09-06-21
1    0      08-06-21
2   -1      09-06-21
```

Comment: I get error "Can only use .str accessor with string values!" when I try execute line "cond=df['Deadline'].str.startswith('00')"

Comment: what is the output of `type(df.loc[0,'Deadline'])`

Comment: @JoãoGaldino Updated answer...Kindly have a look and If your query is solved then try considering accepting the answer **:)**

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I fixed it on my profile and accepting the answer!!

Comment: the line"f['Deadline']=pd.to_datetime(df.loc[cond,.......line']),yearfirst=True)" started to return "Unknown string format: None"  now without having modified the code or the database   @Anurag Dabas

Comment: @JoãoGaldino ohh...that was because of `None` present in the column so pass `errors='coerce'`.....updated answer....didn't saw your reply so sorry for late replying

Answer (score 1):

You can convert ['days'] to string and slice off the first two characters.

- df['days'] = df['days'].str[:2]
- df['days'].astype(int)
- df['Deadline'] = df['Deadline'].str.lstrip('00')
- df['Deadline']=df['Deadline'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%y')
- df['new deadline'] = df['Deadline'] + df['days']

I like Anurag's conditional slicing of Deadline. Unless all of the deadline values start with "00". In which case you should remove the leading 2 zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) as follows:

```
df['Days'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Days']).dt.days
df['Deadline'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Deadline'], format=("00%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%y')
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   Days  Deadline
0    -1  09-06-21
1     0  08-06-21
2    -1  09-06-21
3    -1  09-06-21
4    -2  10-06-21
5    -1  09-06-21
6    -2  10-06-21
7    -2  10-06-21
8    -6  14-06-21
9    -6  14-06-21
```